# How do I assign security groups and subnet using boto3 create_instances()?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to assign a list of security groups and a subnet to AWS instances I'm creating in python.

I'm getting an error when I do stating that the security groups I'm assigning do not exist in the VPC I'm specifying:

```
An error occurred (InvalidGroup.NotFound) when calling the RunInstances The security group 'sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb' does not exist in VPC 'vpc-68b1ff12'
```

However, that's not accurate as the CLI will attest to. Those security groups DO in fact exist in that VPC I'm specifying.

```
 aws ec2 describe-security-groups --filters=Name=vpc-id,Values=vpc-68b1ff12 --profile=my-aws-account | jq -r '.SecurityGroups[].GroupId'
sg-031ac185d029cd5fd
sg-05ef09508245e56bc
sg-0afa867f9029bb468
sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb
sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3
sg-2cad407c
```

You'll see that the SGs listed in the error as not present in the VPC are in the list of SGs that are part of that VPC. They are the same so this confirms that the SGs exist in that VPC.

This is the code that I am using to create the instances:

```
image_id = input("Enter an AMI ID: ")
max_count = input("Enter how many EC2 Servers: ")
key_name = input("Enter the key name to use: ")
instance_type = input("Enter the instance type: ")
name_tag = input("Enter the name tag: ")
aws_account = input("Enter the account name: ")
region = input("Enter the region: ")
    sg_list = input("Enter a comma separated list of security groups to add: ")
    sg_list = str(sg_list)
private_ip_answer = input("Specify an ip address (y/n): ")
if private_ip_answer.lower() == 'y' or private_ip_answer.lower() == 'yes':
    private_ip = input("Enter a private ip addres: ")
else:
    private_ip = ''

def create_instances(image_id, max_count, key_name, instance_type, name_tag, aws_account, region, subnet_id, sg_list, private_ip):
    session = boto3.Session(profile_name=aws_account, region_name=region)
    ec2_resource = session.resource("ec2")
    instances = ''
    instances = ec2_resource.create_instances(
    ImageId=image_id,
    InstanceType=instance_type,
    KeyName=key_name,
    MaxCount=max_count,
    MinCount=1,
    DisableApiTermination=True,
    InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior='stop',
    NetworkInterfaces=[
        {
            'AssociatePublicIpAddress': False,
            'DeleteOnTermination': True,
            'DeviceIndex': 0,
            'Groups': [
                sg_list,
            ],
            'PrivateIpAddress': private_ip,
            'SubnetId': subnet_id
        }
    ]
    )
```

So why is boto3 insisting that these SG identifiers do not exist in the VPC the VPC I'm selecting? How can I get this working? I need to be able to specify BOTH the security groups and the subnet.

Comment: `split` splits on a space, not a comma, as you have specified for the user to enter. if you notice in your traceback every SG has a trailing comma after it

Comment: I've updated the OP. I've removed the `split` command, but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: you didn't need to remove the `split` command you just needed to modify it by providing the proper argument, in this case it would be `split(',')` so that it splits on the comma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says that the single security group named

```
'sg-05ef09508245e56bc, sg-2cad407c, sg-0afa867f9029bb468, sg-0e4b5fc1d40185fc3, sg-031ac185d029cd5fd, sg-0d0ddf3117d23cadb'
```

Does not exist.  Python expects a list, and you're passing it a list that consists of a single string of comma separated items.  The correct act is to use split to create a list of items:

```
NetworkInterfaces=[
        {
            'AssociatePublicIpAddress': False,
            'DeleteOnTermination': True,
            'DeviceIndex': 0,
            'Groups': sg_list.split(','),
            'PrivateIpAddress': private_ip,
            'SubnetId': subnet_id
        }
    ]
```